# Updates to Watson Node.js SDK for Conversation Service

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson

I am waiting for the IBM Watson Conversation updates to the Node.js API to add/update entities and workspaces. I see this https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#create_value , but it has been saying "Coming soon" for a few months now. Any ETA on the npm package support ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, only for `Python` and my [watson-conversation-tool](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/) project. The [Watson Node SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk) has already been updated and you can use the API to manage entities and workspaces.

The Node.js API for Watson Conversation: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/conversation/v1.js